# selectize.js add option dynamically with class attribute

Tags: selectize.js

I am trying to dynamically add an option to the select dropdown
I use the following code:

```
selectize.addOption({value:tuples[key].label,text:value});
```

However now I also **want to add a class attribute** to the option tag.

I tried the following:

```
selectize.addOption({value:tuples[key].label,text:value,'class':'subdivide'});
```

However it does not add the class "subdivide" to the option
Could anybody suggest how can I add the class attribute to the option tag when adding the option.